# Read() integer in c

Tags: c

I tried code below, but the results aren't correct. I think that something with size of buffer can be implemented in a wrong way.

```c
int f(int* as) {
    *as = read(STDIN_FILENO, as, sizeof(int));
} //i print 123

int s;
f(&s);

printf("%d",s); // prints 4
```

Comment: Why do you think the results aren't correct?  What do you expect to happen?  What input are you giving the program?  Try giving an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), inculding input and say what you expect to happen and why you think it is wrong.

Comment: It's probably the size returned by the `read()` function.

Comment: @ChrisDodd  I want to save read value into `s` - so in  this case 123. I don't know why the size instead of value is returned, this happens because `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: Yes you are telling it to read that many bytes.

Comment: Okay, I understand it, but how can I get value by `read()` if it returns length in this (most appropriate for me) way?

Comment: See: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that prevent the program to give the result you expect

1) using `read` to read from standard input (characters) and store that into a (binary) integer

2) storing the result of `read` into that same integer, overwriting the (wrong) value stored in 1)

Have a look at `scanf` or `fgets` (`atoi`...), to read into a character array (string), *then* convert the characters read into a binary number, for instance

```
char str[20];
fgets(str, 20, stdin);
int s = atoi(str);
```

`read` version

```
char str[20];
ssize_t nread = read(STDIN_FILENO, str, 20);
int s = atoi(str);
```

See [what an integer is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Fixed-width_integer_types),

Comment: Wait, so there is no way to get it by `read()`? I have an assignment, implement `scanf()` without any library functions except for `read()`..

Comment: Of course it can, see edit. However for reading strings we usually prefer `fgets` that reads a line at a time (max size or until `\n`) ; `read` is a lower level function used for binary stuff, when you want to read exactly a given size. Does work too. (and `fgets` calls `read` at some point).

Comment: Okay, I get the idea, but `atoi` is "forbidden" too.. Should I think about making some pointers and casting to `int *`?

Comment: Try with `sscanf(str, "%d", &s);` or see an [atoi implementation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-implementation-of-atoi/)

Comment: @J.G. there is no magic cast or implicit conversion to interpret a string with a decimal value and return the decimal value as an integer. You need to consider it as an operation with a number of steps: check the first digit, passing a value, multiply by 10 every time there is a new digit and add the appropriate value. You might need to ask a second question or re-word this one.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought about implementation of this function!